# what is the meaning of "revealed values" ?

Tags: ambiguity

i know obviously the meaning of "Value" and "reveale" but i could not understand 
their meaning together in this quote below :

> “Studies of blood flow and oxygen consumption in the brains of
>   food-deprived obese human subjects ***revealed values*** that were well
>   below the normal levels for adult human brains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Studies of blood flow and oxygen consumption in the brains of food-deprived obese human subjects revealed values that were well below the normal levels for adult human brains..

Let me clarify:

> Studies of blood flow and oxygen consumption in the brains of food-deprived obese human subjects revealed **[blood flow and oxygen consumption]** values that were well below the normal levels for adult human brains..

In other words, when they studied food-deprived obese human subjects, the **measurements** (= values) of blood flow (to their brain) and oxygen consumption (by their brain) were revealed to be well below the normal level for normal adult human brains.

Comment: @downvoter: care to elaborate what's wrong with the answer? I'm open to improving it if I know what to improve.

Comment: Certainly. It's inviting similar questions unsuited to a site aimed at linguists. OP does not include definitions showing what the 'meaning[s] of "Value" and "reveale" ' that they 'obviously know' are. ODO gives 'make (previously unknown or secret information) known ...'. General reference. The way to improve the answer is to remove it and close-vote.

Comment: I close-voted. The system should have explained the reason. I do my fair share of feeding back. I've taken the trouble to explain the downvote to you, for instance. It's time some others started. // I don't appreciate the personal comment, and I'll flag if you don't retract. This use of downvotes has been discussed before.

Comment: @Radwan Cherfy  There is a sister site for learners of English. This provided with the intention of keeping ELU as a place devoted solely to more advanced questions. When people showing a lack of command of the basics insist on having basic questions answered here in spite of the advice at the Help Center, I'd say that they are the ones misusing the site.